# Why are some arrays not properly aligned for vectorization in Fortran?

Tags: arrays, fortran, alignment, vectorization, memory-alignment

I'm trying to improve a Fortran 77 code by vectorizing a for loop. I'm fairly new to vectorization and while I can get the code to vectorize, an optimization report tells me that some of my arrays have unaligned access. This makes, as far as I understand it, the vectorization less efficient.
I have manually added padding to my arrays in order to align the data and this seems to work for most of my arrays, but not for all of them (see example code).

```
      SUBROUTINE SOURCE
      PARAMETER(NLINES=8)
      PARAMETER(NLM=NLINES-1)
      PARAMETER(NZ=18)
      
      COMMON/TEST/h(-nlines:nlines+15,-nlines:nlines)
     &,hr(-nlines:nlines+15,-nlines:nlines)
      COMMON/PRO/P2(-nlm:nlm+1,-nlm:nlm)

      dimension SNT(-nlm:nlm+1,-nlm:nlm,0:NZ+1)

      DO iy=-nlm,nlm
       DO ix=-nlm,nlm
        H(ix,iy)=SNT(ix,iy,1)
     &  +SNT(ix,iy,0)
     &  +SNT(ix,iy,2)

        HR(ix,iy)=P2(ix,iy)*H(ix,iy)
       enddo
      enddo      
      END
```

And the relevant part of the optimization report:

```
   LOOP BEGIN at SOURCE.FPP(13,8)
      remark #15389: vectorization support: reference h(ix,iy) has unaligned access   [ SOURCE.FPP(14,9) ]
      remark #15388: vectorization support: reference snt(ix,iy,1) has aligned access   [ SOURCE.FPP(14,9) ]
      remark #15388: vectorization support: reference snt(ix,iy,0) has aligned access   [ SOURCE.FPP(14,9) ]
      remark #15388: vectorization support: reference snt(ix,iy,2) has aligned access   [ SOURCE.FPP(15,9) ]
      remark #15389: vectorization support: reference hr(ix,iy) has unaligned access   [ SOURCE.FPP(18,9) ]
      remark #15388: vectorization support: reference p2(ix,iy) has aligned access   [ SOURCE.FPP(18,9) ]
      remark #15389: vectorization support: reference h(ix,iy) has unaligned access   [ SOURCE.FPP(18,9) ]
      remark #15381: vectorization support: unaligned access used inside loop body
      remark #15305: vectorization support: vector length 4
      remark #15399: vectorization support: unroll factor set to 3
      remark #15300: LOOP WAS VECTORIZED
      remark #15448: unmasked aligned unit stride loads: 4 
      remark #15450: unmasked unaligned unit stride loads: 1 
      remark #15451: unmasked unaligned unit stride stores: 2 
      remark #15475: --- begin vector cost summary ---
      remark #15476: scalar cost: 15 
      remark #15477: vector cost: 4.250 
      remark #15478: estimated potential speedup: 2.340 
      remark #15488: --- end vector cost summary ---
      remark #25456: Number of Array Refs Scalar Replaced In Loop: 3
      remark #25015: Estimate of max trip count of loop=1
   LOOP END
```

Why don't h(ix,iy) and hr(ix,iy) have aligned access? And how can I align them for better vectorization?

Probably also relevant information:

```
Intel(R) Fortran Intel(R) 64 Compiler for applications running on Intel(R) 64, Version 19.0.0.117 Build 20180804

Compiler options: -qopt-report=5 -c -DLINUX -O3 -w -assume nounderscore -xCORE-AVX2 -o SOURCE.o193
```

Thanks in advance for your time and help!

Comment: https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/data-alignment-to-assist-vectorization.html may be of use, found by googling the warning and following the links. Note the comments about the problems pre-historic language features like common can cause - if you can I would really take the opportunity to modernise by use of modules. Note this is for the Intel compiler, what you are trying to do is ultimately not portable.